# Is there a way to change certain latitudes to zero in matlab?

Tags: matlab, nan

So, I'm trying to perform an oceanography calculation that does not apply to tropical latitudes, therefore, I need to remove any latitudes between 30N and 30S by turning them into zeros.
I've tried doing this as follows:

```
lat = th_lim(1):1/5.999:th_lim(2); 
lat_no_tropics(30>lat>-30) = 0;
lat_no_tropics(isinf(lat_no_tropics)|isnan(lat_no_tropics)) = 0;
```

th_lim is the latitude limits within the data I'm using (-90.0833 and 90.0833).
The 1/5.999 was selected to give lat the same dimensions as the other masks which will be used in the calculations.
However, the output of this is that lat_no_tropics (although it has the right dimensions) is just a series of zeros, nothing more.

If anyone is able to shed any light onto where I'm going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `30>lat>-30` is where you're going wrong I'd say. Better would be to do `abs(lat)<30`, or `lat<30 & lat > -30`, because chaining logical expressions can lead to odd results. Basically `idx = abs(lat)<30;` gives you (linear) indices of your tropical latitudes, and lets you use that as e.g. `data(idx,:)=0` to put those to zero.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the values to zero that are within a range the following way:

```
% create data
lat = (rand(100,1)*100)-50;

% thresholds:
th_lower = -30;
th_upper = 30;

% set data within thresholds to 0
lat((th_upper > lat) & (lat > th_lower)) = 0;
```

Comment: Just for clarity I'd go with `lat < th_upper` rather than the other way around, but it works the same of course.